# Entre « au point mort » et « dans l'impasse », existe-t-il une nuance de sens ?

Tags: sens, expressions

> Tant qu'il ne parlera pas, l'enquête sera **au point mort**.

À mon avis :

Ce contexte-ci me porte à croire que la phrase « au point mort » veut dire que quel que soit l'obstacle à franchir, c'est estimé temporaire. D'autant que la phrase « tant que » indique que dès que la condition précisée là-dedans ne tiendra plus (c'est-à-dire une fois que sa langue se déliera), ils s'en tireront.

Par contre, j'imagine que l'on utilise la phrase « dans l'impasse » quand il ne risque pas d'y avoir d'issue à l’horizon. Peut-être bien qu'il s'agit du pire des cas dans lequel on peut se retrouver.

Comment: Plutôt que dans l'impasse, on utilise dans *une* impasse.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **Au point mort**

*Au point mort* désigne le fait qu'aucune vitesse n'est enclenchée dans une voiture donc le moteur n'a aucun contrôle sur les roues ("it is not engaged"). Donc rien ne bouge. Néanmoins, si quelque chose de neuf se présente (c'est-à-dire que l'on passe une vitesse), les choses peuvent avancer, donc on va vers la solution du problème.

> **Dans l'impasse**

Si on est dans une impasse (i.e. "dead-end") on n'a pas d'autre choix que de faire demi-tour !

**Pour résumer**, *au point mort* désigne le fait qu'on est temporairement à l'arrêt en attendant de nouveaux éléments alors que *dans une impasse* décrit une situation sans issue et il va falloir trouver une autre idée.